# jQuery set attribute with .attr() view source not updating

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to jQuery and am [learning](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/attributes/) about the `.attr()` object method.

I have:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('a').attr('href', 'http://www.google.com');
        console.log( $('a').attr('href') );

    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The console does return the expected value of: `http://www.google.com` but when I right click the window to view the source the anchor element is still: `<a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>`

Why is this?

Comment: works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/ftjc1c7w/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View source shows the original source of the page like it was when it came from the server.

To view generated/modified source, use the developer tools (inspect element)

This is the case in Chrome at least.